# Java - Restricting a method to return generics like T<S>

Tags: java, generics, types, syntax

Is there any way in java for restricting a method to return `T<S>` like this code?

```
public <T extends MyOwnCls1, S extends MyOwnCls2> T<S> func(Class<T> c1, Class<S>... c2) {
  ...
}
```

There is a problem with `<S>` in `T<S>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible only if `MyOwnCls1` has generic type:

```
public <T extends MyOwnCls1<S>, S extends MyOwnCls2> T func(Class<T> p1, Class<S>... p2) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Covariance is applicable to the base type, therefore you should be able to write it without the bounded parameter on `MyOwnCls1`:

```
public <S extends MyOwnCls2> 
       MyOwnCls1<S> func(Class<? extends MyOwnCls1> p1, Class<S>... p2) {

}
//Kept p1 just as I suppose you need it in code.
```

And you should be able to use it with a subtype of `MyOwnCls1`:

```
MyOwnSubCls1<MyOwnSubCls2> res = func(MyOwnSubCls1.class, MyOwnSubCls2.class);
```

The parameter `Class<? extends MyOwnCls1> p1` is only there for the use in your method and should not cause your generic types to become invalid, unless your method implementation expects a different link between `MyOwnCls1` and `MyOwnCls2`